# Not able to consume WCF services in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf

I am getting a strange error.The code was working fine few days back. But now its throwing error. I tried to googling to find out the solution but not able to find it. 
I am creating an entities using code first in entity framework. Now,while adding a new entities using code first in entity framework and consuming the methods using WCF service in MVC, its start throwing error in UI part (MVC) like

**Error:    Cannot implicitly convert type 'Campus.Web.ViewModel.CampusWebService.ExpenseAccount[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'**

**Newly created class in EF**

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(AccountCategoryMajor))]
[KnownType(typeof(ActivityReport))]

[XmlInclude(typeof(AccountCategory))]
public class AccountCategory : BaseEntity
{

    [DataMember]
    public long AccountcategoryMinnorID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual List<AccountCategoryMinnor> AccountCategoryMinnors { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public long ExpenseID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual Expense expense { get; set; }

}
```

when i deleted my newly created class entities its start working fine. I don't know y it is happening.
I am able to run Wcf services alone even and even i am getting entities relationship in the backend.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can convert the `Array` to `List` while consuming, by using the `ToList()` method.

Answer (score 1):

While adding Service Reference in Advanced button change the Collection type to System.Collections.Generic.List would resolve the issue

Comment: Amir i already did this while adding the Service Reference  in MVC.

Comment: browse the AccountCategoryMinnor in MVC part of your solution to see if ExpenseAccount defined as an array or a list. it would be helpfull to Reuse defined types in Service Reference-->Advanced-->Reuse types in specific referenced assemblies

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues. Cleaning the solution, rebuilding and restarting Visual Studio always worked (really).

You could also try to use Array instead of List in your DataContract and convert it to List on the client side.